# used scheduler greatest stack depth error

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, qemu

I have built the linux kernel 3.14 with debug info. When I tried to boot it gives following error and after that booting freezes

Can somebody tell me how to fix this ?

Linux Version : Slitaz in Qemu

[image]

Comment: Have you successfully managed to boot any other kernel build?

Comment: no....but default kernel works

Comment: When you say the default kernel works on what are you basing that? I need more details. What's the QEMU command line you are using? What is the kernel config you have built? Where is your rootfs?